# Python parsing C file - finding function starting with xxx_(...)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a c source file, and find all functions that match the following template:

umsg_xxxxx_yyyy_zzz(aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd)

examples:

```
umsg_test_uints_subscribe(1,1)
umsg_sensors_imu_receive(sub,&msg,portMAX_DELAY)
umsg_sensors_imu_publish(&imu_data);
umsg_sensors_imu_peek(&peek_msg);
```

I've tried something like this:

```
f = open(file)
print(file)

# find words starting with umsg_ and ending with )
for line in f:
    if re.search(r'umsg_[a-z]+\(.*\)', line):
        print(line)
```

But it fails to find anything.

Could anyone help me figure out the regex expression?

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  That regex works successfully for me with a sample line of `umsg_xxx(a,b,c,d)`.  Show us the c source file that you're using.

Comment: that was just the template. I've added concrete examples :)

Comment: That regex only allows letters between `umsg_` and the opening parentheses, but your actual data also has underscores.

Comment: As an aside, that regex would also find `aumsg_whatever()` etc. If you want to find a word boundary before `umsg`, try `\b`

Comment: Can there be nested parentheses in the arguments (e.g. `umsg_foo_bar( (x+y) / 2 )`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a pattern matching 1 or more word characters that can also match an underscore, and a negated character class to match from `(...)`

```
umsg_\w+\([^()]*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GtiVdq/1)

Or another variation starting with a word boundary, and matching word characters without consecutive underscores:

```
\bumsg(?:_[^\W_]+)+\([^()]*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eJw4od/1)

Comment: Those do the trick. Thanks for the help! Much appreciated!